# Manipulating dictionary data structures

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two large dictionaries, one in this structure, i'll call this dict_1:

```
{'hand': [['hand','ball_1_r1','cake_1'],
          ['hand','ball_1_r1','cake_2'],
          ['hand','ball_1_r1','cake_3'],
          ['hand','ball_1_r2','cake_1'],
          ['hand','ball_1_r2','cake_2'],
          ['hand','ball_1_r2','cake_3'],
          ['hand','ball_2_r1','cake_1'],
          ['hand','ball_2_r1','cake_2'],
          ['hand','ball_2_r1','cake_3'],
          ['hand','ball_2_r2','cake_1'],
          ['hand','ball_2_r2','cake_2'],
          ['hand','ball_2_r2','cake_3']]}
```

and another in this structure, dict_2:

```
{'hand': [['hand','ball_1','r1'],
          ['hand','ball_1','r2'],
          ['hand','ball_2','r1'],
          ['hand','ball_2','r2']]}
```

there are multiple items along with their corresponding keys in both dictionary, but all in the same structure as presented here. dict_2 is some transformation of the data in dict_1 such that:

```
{'hand': [['hand','ball_1_r1','cake_1'],
          ['hand','ball_1_r1','cake_2'],
          ['hand','ball_1_r1','cake_3']],
```

is equal to:

```
{'hand': ['hand','ball_1','r1'],
```

I would like to create a third dictionary to get the data in dict_1 in a similar format as dict_2 , so that all the information in the 'cakes' are contained in one list:

```
{'hand': [['hand','ball_1_r1','cake_1','cake_2','cake_3'],
          ['hand','ball_1_r2','cake_1','cake_2','cake_3'],
          ['hand','ball_2_r1','cake_1','cake_2','cake_3'],
          ['hand','ball_2_r2','cake_1','cake_2','cake_3']]}
```

All of my attempts have failed so far. I've been using a list that contained all the keys, which are the same in both dictionaries to iterate over and try and produce a result: `list_1 = ['hand',....]`

Since I know my cake values will only ever range from 1 to 3 and that my r values will only go from 1 to 2 I guess I can do something like this, but I'm looking for something more general and not as 'hacky'

```
new_dict = {}
for values in dict_1.values():
for i in range(0,3):
    if i == 0:
        new_dict['hand'] = [[values[i][i], values[i][i+1], values[i][i+2], values[i+1][i+2], values[i+2][i+2]]]
    if i == 1:
        new_dict['hand'].append([values[i-1][i-1], values[i+2][i], values[i-1][i+1], values[i][i+1], values[i+1][i+1]])
    if i == 2:
        new_dict['hand'].append([values[i-2][i-2], values[i+4][i-1], values[i-2][i], values[i-1][i], values[i][i]])
        new_dict['hand'].append([values[i-2][i-2], values[i+7][i-1], values[i-2][i], values[i-1][i], values[i][i]])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: That said, the term for combining similar entries like this, is *unflatten*.  You are keying off two value entries; this is a non-traditional case.  However, the same principles will help.  I'll keep this bookmarked and look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a flash of Pythonic clarity while packing up.
Here's a starting point for you.  Can you take it form here?
**itertools.groupby()** gathers items in an iterable by value, according to a function you can supply.  I supplied a function that simply combines the first two fields into a tuple.  **groupby** then generates the items in each grouping, in order.

This returns all the entries in the dictionary value, grouped by the first two elements (hand & ball); from that, I stripped out the final element, **n[2]**.  I expect that you already know enough to put the newly formed items back the way you want them in the dictionary.

```
import itertools

hand_dict = {'hand': [['hand','ball_1_r1','cake_1'],
                      ['hand','ball_1_r1','cake_2'],
                      ['hand','ball_1_r1','cake_3'],
                      ['hand','ball_1_r2','cake_1'],
                      ['hand','ball_1_r2','cake_2'],
                      ['hand','ball_1_r2','cake_3'],
                      ['hand','ball_2_r1','cake_1'],
                      ['hand','ball_2_r1','cake_2'],
                      ['hand','ball_2_r1','cake_3'],
                      ['hand','ball_2_r2','cake_1'],
                      ['hand','ball_2_r2','cake_2'],
                      ['hand','ball_2_r2','cake_3']]}

for key, value in hand_dict.iteritems():
    # unflatten the entries in "value"
    for k, v in itertools.groupby(value, lambda row: [row[0], row[1]]):
        k.extend([n[2] for n in v])
        print k
```

output:

```
['hand', 'ball_1_r1', 'cake_1', 'cake_2', 'cake_3']
['hand', 'ball_1_r2', 'cake_1', 'cake_2', 'cake_3']
['hand', 'ball_2_r1', 'cake_1', 'cake_2', 'cake_3']
['hand', 'ball_2_r2', 'cake_1', 'cake_2', 'cake_3']
```